# Need to develop Stock tracker Application in Android using Google Finance API?

Tags: android, finance

I need to develop a Stock Tracker Application using Google Finance API . i searched a lot for the same but i'm unable to find a good tutorial where Step by step tutoring of the same is done. i didnt find the official googla Finance APi documentation much helpful for Android development.

```
Can anyone suggest a good tutorialfor my above query?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should be aware of the limitations.  The finance API allows you to track a given portfolio as entered in Google Finance.  It allows you to get a list of positions (owned stocks) and transactions that are associated with a given google account.  It also allows you to see the current market value, and gains/losses of your overall position.  It does not allow querying of the market price of a given stock ticker or to generate graphs or anything else along those lines.  Essentially, an api to view the content of http://www.google.com/finance/portfolio?action=view and nothing else.

As for the way to get the data, look at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/ to fetch the data.  There are samples in place.  You will need to get authentication working because portfolios are tied to accounts.  Once you have authentication, you can pull and push updates through the provided classes.